# How do I display my tweaks preference bundle in an application?

Tags: theos

I have been developing a tweak and I want to have my preferences in a separate app kind of like how activator does its preferences.

https://github.com/withertech/NewTermTM

I’ve never made an app before and I don’t have access to Xcode or anything because I don’t own a Mac because they are potatoes.

Comment: You need to provide some code for people to help you with your question.

Comment: I linked my GitHub with all of my tweaks code